# Проблема с CORS в react-native приложении

Tags: react-native, fetch, cors, expo

Вопрос, в общем, в большей степени принципиальный. Я столкнулся с невозможностью получить данные со стороннего API с помощью GET запроса. Если бы речь шла о браузерном приложении, я бы не удивился так как это именно браузеры не позволяют получать данные с нарушением CORS. Но в данном случае проблема всплыла в react native приложении на android устройстве. Просто интересно, где тут заложен механизм, реализующий CORS? Запрос делаю с помощью FETCH api. Есть ли альтернативы FETCH, позволяющие обойти проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: а можно подробности по ошибке? уверены что в CORS дело?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема точно не может быть в `CORS`, как правильно вы заметили, в браузерах идет эта проверка. Из сайта:

> The security model for XMLHttpRequest is different than on web as there is no concept of CORS in native apps.

Возможно в настройках `AndroidManifest.xml` проблемы.
А еще может вы пытаетесь по `http` обращаться к серверу, а нужно по `https`.

Comment: Хм, спасибо, буду дальше копать. Вообще, в данном случае проблему обошел установкой на heroku реверсивного прокси cors-anywhere (https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere), поэтому и грешу на CORS. И да, обращаюсь по https.

Comment: Еще момент - приложение не чистое native, а с expo. Нужно попробовать еще без expo. Возможно оттуда какие то ограничения идут.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, пытаясь воспроизвести ошибку, убрал в запросе реверсивный прокси, и всё чудесным образом заработало как надо. Почитал документацию, да, CORS не должен работать в react native приложениях, как в браузерах. Не знаю, что вызвало ошибку ранее. Делал приложение чисто для себя пару месяцев назад. Прекрасно работая на эмулированном в Android Studio девайсе, отказалось работать на физическом телефоне. Сейчас вдруг все заработало. Вопрос закрыт. Спасибо.